# Difficulty installing Laravel 4 and phpmyadmin on an amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, laravel

So, I installed Laravel 4 on an amazon EC2 instance by following this [tutorial](http://www.tonylea.com/2013/installing-laravel-on-amazon-ec2/):

Basically, my steps included:

———- Installing Apache ———-

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
```

———- Installing PHP ———-

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

———- Installing PHP Mcrypt ext. ———-

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

———- Installing MYSQL ———-

```
$sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

———- Installing GIT ———-

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core
```

———- Laravel GIT Repo ———-

```
sudo su 
mkdir laravel    
cd laravel/
git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
```

———- Installing Composer ———-

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
```

Now, I am trying to install phpmyadmin on the EC2 instance, and I am at a loss on how to go about doing it. I am a newbie

So should I install it in the laravel folder?

I have tried this:

downloading the phpmyadmin file

sudo wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/3.3.9.1/phpMyAdmin-3.3.9.1-all-languages.tar.gz

unzipping

```
tar -jxf phpMyAdmin-3.4.1-all-languages.tar.bz2
```

renaming

```
mv phpMyAdmin-3.4.1-all-languages phpmyadmin
```

Obviously it is not done, and I dont think I am doing this at the right folder. Please help anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhpMyAdmin has nothing to do with Laravel and isn't required at all; you can manage your MySQL database using the command line client, the [MySQL workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) or PHPMyAdmin running on a remote computer (assuming it can connect to your DB running on your EC2 instance).

I would recommend not installing PHPMyAdmin as it's always a target for vulnerability scanners and can be vulnerable (plus it's one more thing to keep up to date).

If you still want to use it then extract its tar file somewhere else (not in Laravel's directory), and then change your Apache configuration to redirect something like "/pma" or "/phpmyadmin" to that directory.

If you're using Ubuntu, then you can just install PhpMyAdmin with the package manager, with this command :

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Just follow the instructions, enter your MySQL root password when asked and that's it, your Apache configuration will be updated automatically, and then you can access it on http://server/phpmyadmin.

See the [PhpMyAdmin article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin) in the Ubuntu documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as I said..I am a newb

Comment: Hey Andre, thanks! I was not sure in which folder I should install phpmyadmin. I realized that was a rather silly question... Your answer helped!